# Endless peninsula world

Tags: story-identification, novella

Trying to recall name of novella originally printed in Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine. The story involved a character traversing a world that consisted of a single peninsula bounded by two seas.

Comment: Without wishing to be nitpicky something can't be a peninsula if its the only landmass.

Comment: @DJClayworth Would it just be a continent? I'd think 'island' wouldn't be correct since it would divide the water into 2 distinct bodies rather than being completely surrounded by a single body of water (hope that made sense). And it wouldn't be an 'isthmus' since it's not connecting 2 larger landmasses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was Kim Stanley Robinson's "A Short, Sharp Shock", from 1990.

[A Short Sharp Shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Short,_Sharp_Shock)

> A Short, Sharp Shock (sometimes titled Short, Sharp Shock) is a 1990
>   fantasy novel by Kim Stanley Robinson.[1] The story deals with a man
>   who awakens without memory in a strange land and journeys through it
>   to find the woman he woke alongside.
>
> His journey takes him along the narrow strip of land, surrounded by
>   ocean, which makes up the whole world. The content is unlike anything
>   found elsewhere in Robinson's oeuvre, yet the themes remain very
>   similar. The strong link between the human characters and the natural
>   world connects directly to the ecological themes of his other work,
>   especially the Mars Trilogy, but the loose and dreamlike structure is
>   like nothing else he has written. The novel exhibits a circular
>   structure, with the end harking back to the beginning, suggesting the
>   theme of reincarnation that Robinson will later make the main subject
>   of his novel The Years of Rice and Salt.
>
> The phrase "short, sharp shock" is taken from Gilbert and Sullivan's
>   operetta The Mikado.

Comment: Congratulations on finding the book you were looking for! Please can you add some detail to this answer, to make clearer *why* it matches your original question (e.g. a link and brief plot description)? You can also *accept* your own answer in a day or two, to mark the question as solved.